# MySQL Group By Does Not List All The Group Items

Tags: mysql, group-by

We have tables Teach(cid,pid) and Professor(pid,name) and I want to find all the courses that professor Benjamin taught. Note that there might be more than one professor called Benjamin. So I wrote this query:

```
SELECT T10.cid,T10.pid
FROM Teach T10
WHERE T10.pid IN (SELECT P10.pid FROM Professor P10 WHERE P10.name='Benjamin')
GROUP BY T10.pid
```

But this query just gives 1 course for each pid whose name is Benjamin although there are more courses related to these pids in the tables.

What is the problem?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T10.pid, T10.cid as courses
FROM Teach T10
JOIN Professor P10 ON T10.pid = P10.pid
WHERE P10.name = 'Benjamin'
```

Comment: Since I will use these pid-cids for further computation, I need them on separate rows. To be more precise, after solving above problem, I will check if there is another professor who taught one of Benjamin's all the courses.

Comment: Also, what is the problem with my query?

Comment: If you need all in seperate rows then just remove the `group by`

Comment: Because you group by `pid`. That makes that column unique and only this one. If another column has more values for a unique entry then that does not work.